# run a php file every x seconds on windows

Tags: php, windows

I've read every article about how to make a cron that works for every seconds on windows. But there is no specific detailed article. But I understood I have to make a service that runs a bat file on windows. that bat file should run a loop with sleep to run that php file in CLI.
but I have no idea why php show me an error 'mysql_error' function doesn't exists.
If anyone have any suggestions share with me.

Answer (score 1):

When you run php through the console, the php.ini used is not the same as the one used by apache on most configurations. Write a php file containing only `<?php phpinfo();` and run it under your browser and via cmd.exe (run the command `php \your\dir\file.php > \your\dir\file.txt`, open the file and read it).

You will have more informations about the configs.